# Is it possible to setup ssl certs for a each site on a single iis 6 server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, asp.net, iis-6

I am trying to configure a server running IIS 6 and with hosts multiple sites with a ssl cert and would like to know if that is possible and if anyone has done so before and how

Comment: When you say "multiple sites" do you mean multiple IIS sites, or just multiple web sites (ie. Multiple host names)?  Are the hostnames related (ie. Can you use a wildcard certificate)?

Answer (score 0):

No not possible IIS6 only allows one Cert.

If fred.com , joe.com etc with out mutable names cert.

See link
[Protect Multiple Websites](https://www.godaddy.com/ssl/ssl-certificates.aspx?isc=gofd2003ac&ci=9039)

If fred.com , home.fred.com, work.fred.com wildcard cert will work you will need to run some commands to make it work.

IIS8 and 8.5 allow it now ( remember to set Host name on each site)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is technically possible but requires a good deal of configuring. See this [stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501530/can-iis6-0-host-two-ssl-certificates) and this reference from [digi cert](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/configure-iis-host-headers.htm) and this [MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/anilpras/archive/2012/05/23/server-certificate-bindings-and-its-restrictions-in-iis-6-0-amp-iis-7-x.aspx)

The gist of all of it is that you have a couple of options. If all the websites on your server use the same domain you can use what's called a wildcard certificate and specify *.example.com in your CSR. If instead you don't have a single domain you can use what's called a Subject Alternative Name (SAN) certificate.

While this is still one cert to rule them all, you do get the protection across all the sites which I assume is ultimately your goal.